# SQL: Cumulative summing and insertion into table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider the SQL table

```
  Date     ||   Visits   ||   Purchases
20120403          2               1
20120925          1               0
20130101          1               1
20130405          1               0
20130916          1               0
```

I would like to append a column that is the cumulative sum of visits for the **year**, a column for the cumulative sum of purchases for the **year** and a final column that finds the ratio between the cumulative sum of purchases and visits.

My desired table is therefore

```
  Date     ||  Visits  ||  Purchases  ||  CumVisits  || CumPurchases ||  Ratio
20120403         2             1              2              1            1/2
20120925         1             0              3              1            1/3
20130101         1             1              1              1            1/1
20130405         1             0              2              1            1/2
20130916         1             0              3              1            1/3
```

How would I accomplish the insertion of the cumulative columns and their average in sqlite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t.Date,
    t.Visits,
    t.Purchases,
    SUM(r.Visits) AS CumVisits,
    SUM(r.Purchases) AS CumPurchases,
    SUM(r.Purchases)*1.0/SUM(r.Visits) AS Ratio
FROM t
JOIN t AS r ON r.Date BETWEEN SUBSTR(t.DATE, 1, 4) AND t.Date
GROUP BY t.Date
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/12052/5)

Comment: @Rudie I use to prefer instead of `CAST(... AS FLOAT)`!

Comment: Why CAST it at all? `/` and `*` do that implicitly. And OP's columns are probably INT or NUM so no need. Details.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't work. Try it in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/12052/4)...

Comment: Huh how about that. Two INTs don't make a FLOAT, is what they say. You might want to clarify that in your answer.

Comment: I'm open to OP questions. About division: only MySQL enforces floating point division (http://www.sqlite.org/sqllogictest/wiki?name=Differences+Between+Engines).